# Facebook logs me out after authentication via oauth on external site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

just to recap the process:

1. I call https//graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=.. to get a code.
2. This redirects the user to the facebook login page. They login. A FB session is created in their browser.
3. The browser redirects to http//www.mysite.com/connect/callback?code=..
4. I take that code and exchange it for a token: https//graph.facebook.com/oauth/access … ent_id=...
5. I use that token to call the Graph and REST APIs, doing stuff on the users behalf like querying on me.

To clarify, I know the token works as I can request information on /me.

My problem is that when I access facebook.com in another tab, I get told that I need to log in and it kicks me out.

I've added in functionality to curl to save cookies and I get:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

.facebook.com   TRUE    /       FALSE   1134567810      datr    1121456789-111cabef6e8b649338941b9ab289739a38803ec932211a0bec3ee8
```

Is this correct?  Is there anything more that should be there?

Should I be able to authenticate to FB with my external site and then access FB without getting kicked out?

Thanks for any help, I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore this, as I was always using 1 tab for the facebook page and refreshing it.  Apparently theres something in the links of facebook that carry session data.  Once I started closing the link when I logged out of facebook and then opening either a new window or tab and then logging into facebook, its fine.